# Help me out with this Undefined index ?

Tags: widgets

I'm working on flickr Wp-widget. Here is code to fetch flickr pics.

```
class imperia_flickr extends WP_Widget {

    function imperia_flickr() {
        $widget_ops = array('description' => 'This Flickr widget populates photos from a Flickr ID.' );

        parent::WP_Widget(false, __('imperia - Flickr', 'imperiathemes'),$widget_ops);      
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {  
        extract( $args );
        $id = $instance['id'];
        $number = $instance['number'];

        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title; ?>
        <div class="flickr-icon"></div>
        <?php _e('Photostream'); ?>
            <?php echo $after_title; ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#flickr').jflickrfeed({
            limit: <?php echo $number; ?>,
            qstrings: {
            id: '<?php echo $id; ?>'
          },
            itemTemplate: '<li><a href="{{image_b}}" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img class="flickr" src="{{image_s}}" alt="{{title}}" width="45" height="45"></a></li>'
          }, function(data) {
          $('#flickr a').prettyPhoto();
          });   
            }); 
            </script>        
            <ul id="flickr"></ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
       <?php            
       echo $after_widget;
   }

   function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {                
       return $new_instance;
   }

   function form($instance) {        
    ******  $id = esc_attr($instance['id']);
    ******  $number = esc_attr($instance['number']);
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('id'); ?>"><?php _e('Flickr ID (<a href="http://www.idgettr.com">idGettr</a>):','imperiathemes'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('id'); ?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('id'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>"><?php _e('Number:','imperiathemes'); ?></label>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('number'); ?>" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>">
                <?php for ( $i = 1; $i <= 12; $i += 1) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if($number == $i){ echo "selected='selected'";} ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
} 

register_widget('imperia_flickr');
```

This widget works fine but gives following error

```
-- Debug: Undefined index: id on line 54 of /wp-content/themes/imperia/includes/widgets/widget-imperia-flickr.php
-- Debug: Undefined index: number on line 55 of /wp-content/themes/imperia/includes/widgets/widget-imperia-flickr.php
```

I have marked these lines with ****** above.

Where I'm going wrong ? What needs to be fixed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use isset

```
$id = isset( $instance['id'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['id'] ) : '';
$number = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['number'] ) : '';
```

Comment: after using isset  my page is completely broken & I get error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /Volumes/STUDIO/Workspace/WP - WS/gamma/wp-content/themes/imperia/includes/widgets/widget-imperia-flickr.php on line 55

Comment: I fixed the code.

Comment: Thanks t31os, missed that while editing.
@MANnDAaR now code will work properly